# Logo on Status-Notification Bar Android

Tags: android, image, notifications, status, graphical-logo

How is it possible to place the logo of my app in the notification bar?
I've seen many apps doing that.

For example this one on the left:

[image: screenshot]

Thanks.

Comment: see this so post :: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3712758/controlling-the-android-status-bar-icon

Comment: @abhinav8, thanks, the question seems to be similar, but there's neither accepted answer, nor code example suggested. But will look for that post too.

Comment: I copied your question title into google, the first hit I get is [the official documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html). It explains everything related to notifications, including this, with examples. So maybe search first next time, it would have saved you half an hour in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here they are

```
NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);


private void notification(String message){

    int icon = R.drawable.ic_launcher;
    CharSequence ticket = message;
    long when = System.currentTimeMillis();
    Notification notification = new Notification(icon, ticket, when);
    notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
    CharSequence contentTitle = "Buzz Off";
    CharSequence contentText = message;
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, HomeScreen.class);
    PendingIntent activity = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);
    notification.setLatestEventInfo(this, contentTitle, contentText, activity);
    nm.notify(layout, notification);
    buzzOff = true;
}
```