# android app icon in status bar

Tags: android, icons, statusbar

I am able to make an entry in the notification bar for my app, but I want to make an icon for my app in the status bar, where battery, wi-fi, bluetooth,time icons are shown.
I have searched about this, but got this much- it can't be controlled from the app only, while building android ,some-where in the frameworks directory of android source-code we have to put some lines to get it done,
I don't have any clue how is it managed.

Comment: Its a system control, source code based control :( cant achieve this without editing the source :(

Comment: yes Manoj, I am building source code itself, but not able to find out how can I make an icon for my app, even don't have a clue..

Comment: Try to get the Rom of SGS2 jellybean which has been leaked recently, whch has those kind of controls. might help you :)

Comment: This thing can be achieved yet by source code and can`t be do externally 
as this is protected by the Android OS and not permitted externally to change this thing

Comment: one doubt is here, if I download an app like utorrent to my android tab,I get one icon next to battery icon,so they are maintaining the icon in the app only, may be no need to change in sourcecode..

Comment: I don't know if you'd solved this, but it's definitely possible - the free app widgetsoid manages to put a battery level icon persistently in the notification bar

Answer (score 2):

Sorry I don't have enough reputation to add this as a comment, but have you looked at similar questions like these?. You can add a drawable resource for the icon you want and set flags on your notification so that should allow the icon to remain in the status bar. `FLAG_NO_CLEAR` and    `FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT` can allow you to make an icon appear in the status bar as the answerd to these questions describes.

[How to show an icon in the status bar when application is running, including in the background?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3973208/icon-in-the-status-bar-when-application-is-running)

[controlling the android status bar icon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3712758/controlling-the-android-status-bar-icon?rq=1)

If you have a full checkout of AOSP I would recommend checking out the StatusBarManager service then. The notification uses callbacks inside of this service when showing notificatons. There is also a binder interface that allows setting icons.

in /frameworks/base/services/java/com/android/server/StatusBarManagerService.java and 
/frameworks/base/core/java/com/android/internal/statusbar/IStatusBarService.aidl
`void setIcon(String slot, String iconPackage, int iconId, int iconLevel, String contentDescription);`

`void setIconVisibility(String slot, boolean visible);`

in  /frameworks/base/core/res/res/values/config.xml

```
   <item><xliff:g id="id">ime</xliff:g></item>
    <item><xliff:g id="id">sync_failing</xliff:g></item>
    <item><xliff:g id="id">sync_active</xliff:g></item>
    <item><xliff:g id="id">gps</xliff:g></item>
    <item><xliff:g id="id">bluetooth</xliff:g></item>
    <item><xliff:g id="id">nfc</xliff:g></item>
    <item><xliff:g id="id">tty</xliff:g></item>
    <item><xliff:g id="id">speakerphone</xliff:g></item>
    <item><xliff:g id="id">mute</xliff:g></item>
    <item><xliff:g id="id">volume</xliff:g></item>
    <item><xliff:g id="id">wifi</xliff:g></item>
    <item><xliff:g id="id">cdma_eri</xliff:g></item>
    <item><xliff:g id="id">data_connection</xliff:g></item>
    <item><xliff:g id="id">phone_evdo_signal</xliff:g></item>
    <item><xliff:g id="id">phone_signal</xliff:g></item>
    <item><xliff:g id="id">battery</xliff:g></item>
    <item><xliff:g id="id">alarm_clock</xliff:g></item>
    <item><xliff:g id="id">secure</xliff:g></item>
    <item><xliff:g id="id">clock</xliff:g></item>
```

the are the values for slots that get added by default to the statusbar

Hope this helps

Comment: thanks for your post. But in both the links you have provided.They are talking about app icon in status bar but handling it with notification Manager, I think these are two different features & controlled by different managers.

Comment: I just reread your question a couple of times, so are you trying to add an icon on the right side of the status bar? I edited with another alternative that may be of use potentially

Comment: yes! Swain this may be helpful, I want to put icon in right bottom side. I will try it.

Comment: @linuxD can you share the code/steps please, as exactly what you tried. I am also doing this functionality. Just wanted to see how it can be achieved. Thanks you